# How to show data in table with ngFor in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, ngfor, provider

I got to the point where the table is showing in my Console but not in the table.
First my ts.code:

```
export class InsightsComponent implements OnInit {
    
    invoice: any;
    protected invoices: any[] = [];
   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.provider.getInvoice(this.firmService.getDomain())
            .then(data => {
                this.invoice = data;
            });
    }
```

the provider.ts:

```
export class FirmProvider {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    
  }
    getInvoice(invoiceDomain: string): PromiseLike<InvoiceResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve): void => {
      this.http
        .get<InvoiceResponse>('https://' + invoiceDomain + '.' + environment.domain + 'v1/invoice/', {withCredentials: true}) 
        .subscribe((response: InvoiceResponse): void => {
          console.log(response);
          resolve(response);
        })
    })
  }
}
```

interface:

```
export interface InvoiceResponse{
    type:string,
    title:string,
    status:string,
    detail:string,
    class:string,
    trace: string   }
```

the html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices">
    <td>{{ invoice.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.detail }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.class }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.trace }}</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
```

How do I show it in the table?

Tried using this method:https://www.positronx.io/build-dynamic-html-table-in-angular-with-ngfor/, did not work.

Comment: I see nowhere in the code an `invoices` list/array. Is the returned data from the service already a list?

Comment: I think, you should use `this.invoices = data;` as you are using `invoices` in the `ngFor`

Comment: Plese refer to material table documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I don't get the usage of ngFor directive. The getInvoice function is getting details of a single invoice and You expect the InvoiceResponse object, not array of objects